# JSFiddle + coffescript how to comment out code with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jsfiddle

I like using **http://jsfiddle.net/** for testing, when I learn coffeescript from some tutorials. I would like to comment-out multiple lines. So I click on my Mac `cmd` + `/`, what in most editors is connected with commenting out the selection. In JSFiddle with coffe script set up in language section I got `<!--` and `-->` instead of `#` on each line.

Is there some other key combination to get commented out the selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this feature has been requested but the only thing they have implemented is to comment out as HTML `<!-- -->` for all the panels (HTML, CSS and JS). Check the feature request [here](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/248) and their response to that.

Answer (score 5):

Use this-> select all line which you want to comment then  press **ctrl + /**  to comment all lines in jsfiddle

Comment: `ctrl + #` on QWERTZ